# Implementing strcpy function without using in-built strcpy

Tags: arrays, c, function, c-strings

I am trying to implement a strcpy function without using inbuilt function. I have searched online but I only found the **programs** to do this task but not **functions**.

I tried various approaches but no luck. At the end (Try 4) , I wrote a code that works but I dont understand why the hell is that thing working but previous approaches aren't

Just looking for a function that can copy value of one string into another when called from main() and displays correct value in output string. I would be really thankful if I could get that. And ofcourse, I cant use the inbuilt function because I am forced to do this cuz of an exam on Monday where we will have to implement any of the random 7 string functions and explain the code too..

EDIT: Also found this https://www.programmersought.com/article/29163684184/ code to implement the same thing but it is written in C++. Why does schools/colleges still teach C after the invention of C++? Anyone knows any C++ to C converters?

Try 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcopy(char *a, char *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    char a[10];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", &a);
    printf("Input string: %s", a);
    char b[(sizeof(a))];
    strcopy(a,b);
    printf("\nOutput string: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter string: helloworld
Input string: helloworld
Output string: helloworldhelloworld
```

---

Try 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcopy(char *a, char *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the string size: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char a[n];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf(" %s",&a);
    printf("Input string: %s", a);
    char b[n]; 
    strcopy(a,b);
    printf("\nOutput string: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

```
Enter the string size: 7
Enter string: helloworld
Input string: helloworld  
Output string: helloworldö
```

---

Try 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcopy(char *a, char *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the string size: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n++;
    char a[n];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    // scanf(" %s",&a);
    fgets(a,n,stdin);
    fgets(a,n,stdin);  //need to write twice or it wont work
    printf("Input string: %s", a);
    char b[n]; 
    strcopy(a,b);
    printf("\nOutput string: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the string size: 5
Enter string: helloworld
Input string: hello  
Output string: hello⌂
```

---

Try 4:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcopy(char *a, char *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    n++;
    char a[n];
    scanf(" %s",&a);
    // printf("Enter string: ");
    // fgets(a,n,stdin);
    // fgets(a,n,stdin);
    printf("Input string: %s", a);
    char b[n]; 
    strcopy(a,b);
    printf("\nOutput string: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the string: helloworld
Input string: helloworld 
Output string: helloworld
```

---

**EDIT:**

Trying approach given by a friend in answers:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcopy(char *a, char *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; a[i+1] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    // int n;
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    // scanf("%d",&n);
    // n++;
    char a[10];
    scanf("%s",&a);
    // printf("Enter string: ");
    // fgets(a,n,stdin);
    // fgets(a,n,stdin);
    printf("Input string: %s", a);
    char b[sizeof(a)]; 
    strcopy(a,b);
    printf("\nOutput string: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the string: helloworld
Input string: helloworld
Output string: helloworl
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Trying do-while loop:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcopy(char *a, char *b)
{
    // for (int i = 0; a[i+1] != '\0'; i++)
    // {
    //     b[i] = a[i];
    // }
    int i=0;
    do{
        b[i]=a[i];
        i++;
    }while(a[i] != '\0');
}
int main()
{
    // int n;
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    // scanf("%d",&n);
    // n++;
    char a[10];
    scanf("%s",&a);
    // printf("Enter string: ");
    // fgets(a,n,stdin);
    // fgets(a,n,stdin);
    printf("Input string: %s", a);
    char b[sizeof(a)]; 
    strcopy(a,b);
    printf("\nOutput string: %s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Enter the string: helloworld
Input string: helloworld
Output string: helloworldhelloworld

Comment: "Why does schools/colleges still teach C after the invention of C++?" Because C++ is _not_ a superset of C.  They are, nowadays, two languages with little in common besides ancestry and surface syntax, and _learning_ C teaches you things that learning C++ doesn't (and vice versa).

Comment: But its such a headache learning C when you are never gonna use it. Its syntax is really bad and long as compared to C and has a room for a lot of errors. The code is also much longer and learning C after C++ can get really annoying sometimes because you know the solution/algorithm that can be implemented while coding in one language but not in other. Also, C has many limitations that can be overcome using C++.

Comment: Apart from the problems others mentioned, note that your string `a` has size `10`. That's not enough to store your `"helloworld"` string, which, including its terminating `null`, has `11` bytes.

Comment: See [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/string.h/strcpy), [PPC](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/ppc.subproj/strcpy.c), [memcpy](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1158.30.7/string/strcpy.c.auto.html), [BSD](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/i386/gen/strcpy.c.auto.html).

Comment: Yes, but it seems that C automatically increases the array size in case bigger string is input because its using `%s` format specifier and the code that is written at the top of the post works for strings longer than 15 character too.

Comment: You should avoid identifiers starting with **`str` and a lowercase letter** because they're reserved by the C Standard for expansion of `<string.h>`. See [C11 7.31.13](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.13).

Comment: @BestCodingExpert that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @pmg Yes, I can easily change the function name but as far as i know, C has only 7 string functions. Also, the purpose of writing this code is to avoid using string.h library. So, i think this is fine for now. And yeah, thanks for the advice, i will take care of it while working on my projects.

Comment: ok @user3121023 , but is memory corruption really something I need to worry about in local environment? I mean I am not asking the size of string from the user anyway, and it should display the whole string. And C doesn't have any string datatype like C++ so i think it is fine.

Comment: Ok, BestCodingExpert, let's say you make your own library independent of `<string.h>`... nobody stops "your" users to `#include "bce.h"` **and** `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Lol ok, guys, I will use scanf("%9s") and reverse order of arguments.

Comment: Also, @pmg I am just a student and would never work in C language, especially when there are such better alternatives and next month (end sem) is probably the last time i would ever give any attention to this language so, I dont think I have any "users" who would use my code except someone copy-pasting the code from this post. And I believe function strcopy doesn't interfere with working of functions of any other library. I named it this for easier understanding of the task done by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the olden days when K&R was king, we'd tie a onion to our belts, as was the style at the time and do something like

```
void strcopy(char *a, char *b)
{
   while ( *b++ = *a++ ) {}
}
```

Now I think the old ways are depreciated

It has been suggested that I explain why this works.

`*b = *a` does the core function of copying of one byte

`*b++ = *a++`  Adding the auto-increments, moves both the pointers to the next locations in memory after the assignment is done

`while (*b++ = *a++) {}`  loops while the byte copied is non-zero.  the empty `{}` is just to complete the syntax of the `while` statement

So the while loop will run copying bytes then incrementing both pointers to the next location until the byte copied was zero, being the end of string

Comment: Code dumps without any exposition are worst practice when answering homework questions.

Comment: Thanks @infixed sir, I tried this code and it works perfectly the way it should.

Comment: And @zwol ,  I would like to clarify again that this is not a **homework** question. I would never post any homework/assignment question on stackoverflow. However, if I have any doubt in a technical part during preparation of exams or making projects and I can't find solution online, there is nothing wrong in taking help from the community.

Comment: Nowadays, we would at least add extra parentheses `while ((*b++ = *a++)) {}` for the express purpose of assuring the compiler/linter that we really *meant* to assign instead of compare there.

Comment: @BestCodingExpert The issue is the same regardless of whether this is formally a homework assignment.  You were handed something that works, yes.  Do you have any idea why?  Are you going to be able to explain it on the exam on Monday?

Comment: infixed, in the old days `while ( *b++ = *a++ ) {}` is not a portable solution as the loop stops on -0 when it should not.  Given `char`  encoding is overwhelmingly 2's complement these days, not much a concern.

Comment: Well, yes, I would be able to explain the working code that I is at top of the post easily because I know how it is working and also the reason of each line being written. And this was taught in the class but at that time, it was done using main() function. And the teacher just asked us to write 7 different programs to implement the functions but they can definitely ask to implement it using separate functions on Monday. And I thought of trying it using functions, however, when i found that i am unable to do it, I was determined to find its solution and I found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OP's `strcopy()` has various problems in trying to mimic the standard library function:

```
char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

---

**Missing *null character* in the destination array**

This is OP 's primary issue.  *Somehow* a *null character* must be assigned in the destination.  OP's various codes fail that.

Tip: think about copying a string `""` which assign *only* a *null character* `'\0'` to the destination.

**Wrong parameter order**

The first parameter should be the destination to match `strcpy()`

**Missing return value**

`strcpy()` returns the original destination pointer.

**Advanced: Parameters missing `restrict/const` attributes**

Simply use the library function signature above.

**Advanced: Fails for *long* strings**

OP's code uses `int` to index which is insufficient for *long* strings.  Better to use `size_t`.

**Tip: Add output clarity**

When printing the result, add sentinel characters like `< >`and a final `'\n'`.
For debug efforts, make destination string 2x as big.

```
// char b[sizeof(a)]; 
char b[sizeof(a) *2]; 
strcopy(a,b);
// printf("\nOutput string: %s", b);
printf("\nOutput string: <%s>\n", b);
```

---

OP's asserts this in not a homework coding task, so a candidate solution:

```
char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2) {
  // Use unsigned char as all str functions behave as if char was unsigned
  // Also need to save s1 for return
  unsigned char *us1 = (unsigned char *)s1;
  const unsigned char *us2 = (const unsigned char *)s2;

  while (*us2) {
    *us1++ = *us2++;
  }

  return s1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is a void function supposed to exchange the values so it shouldn't have a return value, and yeah, I know that the parameters are exchanged n I did it on purpose because I think its better and more understandable if source is passed as 1st argument and destination as 2nd. The missing NULL was the mistake which has been fixed with the help of the community and code works fine now. Also, as you can see in the post, the output is already clear and I have copy-pasted the output directly from terminal without any formatting. Never heard about `size_t` before, will surely look into it.

Comment: @BestCodingExpert "function supposed to exchange the values so it shouldn't have a return value" and question's title "Implementing strcpy function without using in-built strcpy" are then in conflict.   "think its better and more understandable if source is passed as 1st argument and destination as 2nd." is an antipattern to the standard C library.  "missing NULL was the mistake" --> better as "missing null character was a mistake" or "missing `'\0'` was a mistake"  Best to use NULL in the context of the _null pointer_ and not a _null character_.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant it was supposed to copy one string into another. And yeah missing '\0' in copied string was mistake not NULL.  Ok, I will change the order of arguments

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding a terminating `\0`.

Comment: I have added '\0' for coparison purpose inside for loop in every try, I am not sure where else should I add it because although, I am really good in C++,  I am not very familiar with C

Comment: Please explain the logic by which you are adding a `\0` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: When the end of string is reached, the copying of the source string to destination string should be stopped and end of string is always '\0'

Comment: @BestCodingExpert Your for loop is only executed if `a[i]` is *not* `\0`, therefore you never copy the null

Comment: i changed it to a[i+1] != '\0' but it still doesn't work

Comment: Sadly you missed to parse out some essential information from my question.
Why would you do this *inside the loop*? It does not make any sense. Had you just added `b[i] = '\0';` *after* the loop, it would have worked fine. So I doubt you are a good programmer in C++. Applying logic and troubleshooting are skills that carry over to other languages. Don't just do shit until it works.

Answer (score 1):

All of your implementations have the same essential bug; "try 4" works only by accident.  The problem is with the loop termination condition in `strcopy`.  When you reach the NUL character that ends the source string, you are stopping the loop and not copying it.  This means that the destination string is not ended and `printf` walks past its end, printing whatever happens to be in memory beyond.  You must instead copy the NUL *and then* stop the loop.

You also have errors in how you allocate memory for the strings `a` and `b` -- different in each implementation, but none of them look abstractly correct to me.  Talk to your instructor about how to do this correctly, it's one of the most complicated subjects in C and I don't have enough information about what techniques you are allowed to use.

Comment: Thanks but actually, I tried implementing your suggestion and that also didnt work. I have added the code and its output at the end of my question

Comment: Changing the way you index the arrays doesn't change the fact that the loop stops before copying the NUL.  Again, the thing that's needed is to copy the NUL _and then_ stop.

Comment: Further hint: try a do-while loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: ok, yeah, you are correct. I didn't notice that but can you please provide the code as changing the index is the only approach I could think of.

Comment: Ok, let me try using do-while

Comment: Sorry, providing the code crosses the line from helping to doing the assignment for you, which I won't do.

Comment: I tried using do-while but it doesn't work. Let me just add that code and its output also as a edit in question. And its alright if you dont want to provide code and just guide me but I would like to clarify that its not an assignnment, just preparation for an exam.

Comment: Still the same essential problem.  Think harder about how you could make the loop stop _after copying the final NUL_ instead of just before copying it.